How to organize Codesys programming
I come from a traditional ladder logic PLC environment like Allen-Bradley. I'm trying to understand OOP for PLCs and I'm trying to write a simple code for a conveyor, jam sensors, estops and control stations along de lane, as practice.
The issue I'm is how would you organize all of this code. Normally, using studio 5000 I would create a subroutine for Conveyors, jam sensors, estops etc. I would create global variables for my devices AOIs and share the tags/ data needed between routines.
Here in Codesys, I'm not sure if everything should be written and instantiated in the main PRG or if there is a way to have several PRGs and share data. (Similar to subroutines in AB). I'm trying to encapsulate and avoid using Global Variables but I guess my mind keeps defaulting to that "traditional" PLC code architecture. Maybe a couple conveyors and sensors would be OK but what happens when you have 100 devices. Would the Main PRG be the best way to have everything instantiated there?
If there is a video, documentation or guidance I could get on this I would greatly appreciate it.
I think using interfaces might be a good way to share information between FBs but I get back to the same issue.... if they are not instantiate in the same program, then I cannot reference them.

https://twincontrols.com/ would be a better place to ask these kind of questions

Getting some training in OO programming/modelling would be very beneficial, because the basic concepts you would get from, say, Java or C# would translate quite directly to structured text.
The general answer to "where do I put my data if I don't have global variables" is : as member variables in function block instances, or as arguments in methods you invoke on these instances.
Function blocks are basically classes. They can specify data (whether single values or structures), nested function blocks, pointers (POINTER TO) or references (REFERENCE TO) that their instances (i.e. each individual variable the type of which is the function block) will have its own copy of. Pointers or references are especially useful because they give access to the thing that is being referenced, not a copy.
If you have a reference to a conveyor inside another function block, then you can act on the conveyor itself using the reference.
Function blocks also contain code (methods). All instances of a function block share the same code, but each has its own independent copy of the data.
They key thing is that the code of a function block has direct access to the data of the instance on which the code is called.
When the instances of a function block need to access something "from the outside", you can add a pointer or reference to that thing inside the function block, and initialize this pointer or reference before execution begins. One way to do that is by passing the pointer/reference to the FB_init method of the function block, which acts a bit like what would be called a "constructor" in most OO languages. In practice, this means adding arguments to the instance's declaration. This is often called "reference injection".
Another possibility is to pass outside information when calling a method on an instance of a function block. Once again this can be values, structures or function blocks, or pointer/references to the same.
An interface is a way to define features that need to be provided by function blocks that are intended to "implement" that interface. Interfaces can be used as types, and they act like references, except that (1) REFERENCE TO is not used, using an interface implicitly involves reference semantics and (2) if you have a reference to an instance of an interface, you only have access to features defined in the interface, not to the full feature set of the function block to which the instance belongs. Once again, interfaces in, say, Java, are analogous to what you find in structured text.
Please note that in many cases, you would get rid of global variables only to define function block instances that, themselves, are globals. But packaging data and code in function blocks will make things simpler. For instance, if you have some kind of gizmo that has 5 inputs and 5 outputs, and you have 10 of these gizmos, instead of having 50 inputs and 50 outputs each declared as a global variable and mapped to I/O devices, you would define one function block with 5 inputs and 5 outputs, and instantiate this function block 10 times. Instead of having a "global routine" that deals with 10 sets of inputs/outputs, you would write one method that deals with the inputs and outputs of one gizmo, but call this method for each instance. You could just as well put these gizmos in an array and call the method from a loop. This makes for code that is smaller, easier to modify and debug.
